# Symfony2 security component documentation

Tags: php, symfony

I was wondering if there was any improvement of the security component documentation ongoing or not? If true, when will it be released?

In any case, do you know any tutorials which explain in detail the functionning of every pieces of the security component?

Comment: Did you see, that you can always switch to the ["master" version of the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/security.html)? What is the problem you achieved and can't resolve yourself using the documentation and the source?

Comment: There isn't any problem, just for my personnal culture because last week I had to implement a custom authentication provider and it was quiet 'epic'. For instance what are the different hooks in the listener and why are they useful (form, pre_auth ...). I also saw that there was session strategy and entry point classes but there is no doc available on the symfony website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have different way to aboard security layer depending on what you need:

- **Firewall** 
  => Help to restrict acces to pages and Roles
- **Authentification provider** 
  => The most usefull : FosUserBundle. Help to manage user and authentification (how to create an auth token...)
- **ACL** 
  => Help to create some rights on items (ex : you have en entity Comment. Then you create a new comment and give ACL to have ownership of the comment to let you edit this item the way you want)
- **Voters** 
  => It's the piece that checks if you can access the element of not

Links :
Firewall : http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html
Auth : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html
ACL : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl.html
Voter : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters.html

Comment: I didn't knew about the voters, thanks. Any other tutorials, blog posts?

Comment: You can go really deep in too each layer. Once you defined what you need, you can find lot's of question/answers on google code and stackoverflow.

Comment: That's a bit of a shame to be forced to face a problem to then ask a question, but well, I suppose this is how it works with sf2 :(

Comment: I join you :) But documentation doesn't detail the weaks otherwise it won't be as popular as it is...